# How can I modify the behavior of every function in an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

Right now I have an object, such as this Pen.

The prototype of the class contains a series of functions and other properties.

```js
var Pen = function(){
   this.inkColor = 'red';

   this.write = function(text){
      document.write(text);
   }

   this.refill = function(){
      console.log('refilling');
   }
   
   this.getInkColor = function(){
      return this.inkColor;
   }
   
};

var pen = new Pen();
pen.write(pen.getInkColor() + ': Hello');
```

Is there away to avoid modifying the Pen class, but change the behavior of every function it has, such as print a log before the actual function call?

```
this.write = function(text){
   // do something first
   document.write(text);
}

this.refill = function(){
   // do something first
   console.log('refilling');
}

this.getInkColor = function(){
   // do something first
   return this.inkColor;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `Pen` doesn't have a *prototype*. The constructor assigns instance methods to the plain object.

Comment: Well, it does, it just has a blank one.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Even then, is there a way to refactor this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the functions with wrappers that call the original and also do something else. For instance:

```
Object.keys(pen).forEach(name => {
    const originalFunction = pen[name];
    if (typeof originalFunction === "function") {
        pen[name] = function(...args) {
            console.log(name, args);
            return originalFunction.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
});
```

That replaces all functions on `pen` (only its own, not ones it inherits) with wrappers that first do a `console.log` then call the original.

Live Example:

```js
var Pen = function(){
   this.inkColor = 'red';

   this.write = function(text){
      // used console.log instead of document.write
      console.log(text);
   }

   this.refill = function(){
      console.log('refilling');
   }
   
   this.getInkColor = function(){
      return this.inkColor;
   }
   
};

var pen = new Pen();

Object.keys(pen).forEach(name => {
    const originalFunction = pen[name];
    if (typeof originalFunction === "function") {
        pen[name] = function(...args) {
            console.log(name, args);
            return originalFunction.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
});

pen.write(pen.getInkColor() + ': Hello');
```

You can tweak that to handle functions inherited from the prototype, or inherited only from `Pen.prototype` (you don't have anything on `Pen.prototype` at present), etc.

Comment: This is kinda like the actual first thing I have tried but somehow I ended up in an endless loop... Cuz I didn't use the apply function..?

Comment: @HaoWu - :-) Probably you did `return pen[name](..)` instead -- which calls your wrapper again, rather than calling the original function. The above works because it calls the original, not the wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your pen in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and define an appropriate handler.

```js
var Pen = function(){
   this.inkColor = 'red';

   this.write = function(text){
      document.write(text);
   }

   this.refill = function(){
      console.log('refilling');
   }
   
   this.getInkColor = function(){
      return this.inkColor;
   }
   
};

var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return name in target ? function (...args) {console.log('Hello World'); return target[name](args)} : undefined;
  }
};


var pen = new Pen();
var p = new Proxy(pen, handler);
p.write(p.getInkColor() + ': Hello');
```

Comment: This works pretty fine normally but unfortunately I can’t change the object instantiation part either. Cuz many of this object instantiated other places, so if the Pen is a prototype I have to modify it’s actual code dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that returns another function:

```
function doSomethingFirst(somethingToDoFirstFn, thingToDoAfterFn) {
  return function() {
    somethingToDoFirstFn.apply(null, arguments);
    thingToDoAfterFn.apply(null, arguments);
  }
} 

var Pen = function(){
   // code

   this.refill = doSomethingFirst(function(){
      console.log('somethingFirst');
   }, function() {
      console.log('refilling');
   })   

   // code
};
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, I can't change the existing code inside of the Pen class(if it is a class). And I don't know exactly how many functions are there inside of it so I have to iterate them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're absolutely right - I'll edit the answer. Got something mixed up here.

Comment: HaoWu use @bnord's solution. A Proxy in this case makes absolute sense